# unfortunately app has stopped , android

Tags: java, android, error-handling, app-store

i have given the code here . and when i run it in genymotion it just stops working. please help .
i dont see any display in logcat also . it remains blank and the emulator only shows an error that is "unfortulately, SharedprefrencEexample has stoped working. and the app dont even starts. so i dont get any clue of what might be the error in this code . 
here i have used the reference creation at the start and i think it might be the error. so please do see the code and help me.
thanks.

**Main_Activity**

```
package com.example.sharedprefrenceexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText name,phone,email;
Button submit;
Intent intent;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    phone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    submit.setText("@string/button_name_activity_one");
    name.setHint("name");
    phone.setHint("phone");
    email.setHint("email id");

    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("@string/database_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editor.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("phone", phone.getText().toString());

            editor.commit();

            intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Secondactivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("email", email.getText().toString());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sharedprefrenceexample.MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/button_name_activity_one" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**secondactivity**

```
package com.example.sharedprefrenceexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Secondactivity extends Activity {

TextView result;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);

    result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("database", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String res = null;
    res=res+sharedPreferences.getString("name", "no name");
    res=res+sharedPreferences.getString("phone", "no phone");

    intent=getIntent();

    res=res+intent.getStringExtra("email");

    result.setText(res);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secondactivity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**activity_secondactivity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sharedprefrenceexample.Secondactivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Get logcat connected and find out what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

```
submit.setText("@string/button_name_activity_one");
// (...)
sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("@string/database_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

That syntax is only valid in XML. In Java code, to use a string reference you should use

```
submit.setText(R.string.button_name_activity_one);
```

So fix those string references and it should work.

More info: [String resources @ Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)